# Fragment's getArguments() method returns null. Using a ViewPager, passing Arguments through a FragmentPager Adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

I pass my data as a parcelableArrayList from Activity-->Adapter-->Fragment. In my static `newInstance()` method, I'm instantiating a `Fragment` and setting its arguments. I check if the arguments are set or not in the `newInstance()` method itself. When I try to access the data in my `onCreate()`, I get a null Pointer Exception.

Adapter where I'm passing the data to fragments:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position){
    switch(position){
        case 0:
            return StatusFragment.newInstance("Hahahahah, Dumbfuck");
        case 1:
            return GraphListFragment.newInstance(position, tempBundle);
        case 2:
            return GraphListFragment.newInstance(position, humBundle);
        case 3:
            return GraphListFragment.newInstance(position, pressureBundle);
        default:
            return GraphFragment.newInstance(1);
    }
}
```

My static newInstance() method:

```
public static Fragment newInstance(int position, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    GraphListFragment graphListFragmentInstance = new GraphListFragment();

    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        Bundle bundle =new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("list", savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("list"));
        graphListFragmentInstance.setArguments(bundle);
        Log.d("==============>>>>", graphListFragmentInstance.getArguments().toString());
    }
    return new GraphListFragment();
}
```

Here's the Log result:

```
 D/==============>>>>: Bundle[{list=[com.ishanvadwala.cmpe295b.Model.TemperatureData@8da04a0, com.ishanvadwala.cmpe295b.Model.TemperatureData@5fce859, com.ishanvadwala.cmpe295b.Model.TemperatureData@9503c1e, com.ishanvadwala.cmpe295b.Model.TemperatureData@6aeecff, ....
```

Here's my onCreate() where I'm trying to access the data:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.d("onCreate====>>>>", getArguments().toString());
        /*
        List<?> list = (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("list");
        if(list.get(0) instanceof TemperatureData){
            for(TemperatureData tempData: (List<TemperatureData>)list){
                System.out.println("I got this: "+tempData.getTemperature());
            }
        }
        */
    }
```

I've looked at several StackOverflow posts and I still have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Where is the null pointer exception? Show the stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
return new GraphListFragment();
```

With

```
return  graphListFragmentInstance;
```

---

That's the actual Fragment with the Bundle!

Also, creating a new Bundle is useless. Just set the one you are passing

```
if(savedInstanceState != null){
    // Bundle bundle =new Bundle(); 
    // bundle.putParcelableArrayList("list", savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("list"));
    graphListFragmentInstance.setArguments(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("==============>>>>", savedInstance.toString());
}

return  graphListFragmentInstance;
```

Comment: Thank You!!!! Sorry for being so stupid! I don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

How to pass args to fragment

**SET**

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("Video1", "Sosis");
bundle.putString("Video2", "Dumb");

Fragment fragment = new YourFragment();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);

// Attach the fragment
```

**GET**

```
public static class YourFragment extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        if (getArguments() != null)
        {
            Log.e(getArguments().getString("Video1", ""));
            Log.e(getArguments().getString("Video2", ""));
        }
    }
}
```